# Get a list of records from a collection sorted by count and uniqueness of a field in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

So I have a bunch of documents in a MongoDB collection and it seems that the collection is growing a little faster than we thought.

Is there a way to get a list from a collection that will count the number of documents that have X as a value in a field.

I’ll just make some data up for example’s sake:

There are 4 values possible for the field `reference`:

1. `/content/public`
2. `/content/private`
3. `/resource/something`
4. `/much/wow`

Is there a way to get a list from mongo that says:

- 1231 Records have `/content/public` as the value for reference.
- 21312312 have `/content/private`.
- 34 have `/resource/something`.
- 34242 have `/much/wow`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of different ways to do this, the brute force approach would be to do a query for each distinct value you are aware of, and just call `.count()` like so:

```
db.collection.find({field : '/content/public'}).count()
db.collection.find({field : '/content/private'}).count()
etc.
```

But, that means you need to iterate through a list of known fields and you have to run a bunch of different queries.  Still, it might be nice for a spot check.

The more general option is the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/).  Something like this would work, where field, as above is the one you are interested in counting values for:

```
db.collection.aggregate( { $group : { _id : "$field", count : { $sum : 1 } } })
```

Here's a generic example with made up data.  First the data itself:

```
> db.foo.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("547ccf922bd17c324ae52b6e"), "countField" : "/content/public" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("547ccf932bd17c324ae52b6f"), "countField" : "/content/public" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("547ccf942bd17c324ae52b70"), "countField" : "/content/public" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("547ccf942bd17c324ae52b71"), "countField" : "/content/public" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("547ccf952bd17c324ae52b72"), "countField" : "/content/public" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("547ccf962bd17c324ae52b73"), "countField" : "/content/public" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("547ccf9b2bd17c324ae52b74"), "countField" : "/content/private" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("547ccf9d2bd17c324ae52b75"), "countField" : "/content/private" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("547ccfa42bd17c324ae52b76"), "countField" : "randomvalue" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("547ccfa52bd17c324ae52b77"), "countField" : "randomvalue" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("547ccfa62bd17c324ae52b78"), "countField" : "randomvalue" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("547ccfa72bd17c324ae52b79"), "countField" : "randomvalue" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("547ccfa72bd17c324ae52b7a"), "countField" : "randomvalue" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("547ccfa82bd17c324ae52b7b"), "countField" : "randomvalue" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("547ccfb52bd17c324ae52b7c"), "countField" : "/much/wow" }
```

Now the sample aggregation:

```
> db.foo.aggregate({ $group : { _id : "$countField", count : { $sum : 1 } } })
{ "_id" : "/much/wow", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "randomvalue", "count" : 6 }
{ "_id" : "/content/private", "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "/content/public", "count" : 6 }
```